# How do I force phones to display screen orientation only "portrait", and tablets to only display screen orientation only "landscape"?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Ionic Framework, ionicframework.com, how do I force phones to display screen orientation only "portrait", and tablets to only display screen orientation only "landscape"?

Answer (score 3):

Add the preference `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in **config.xml** seems to be the way to go, works with Cordova 3.4.1 and later.

Using screen.orientation directly in javascript in the app is more flexible, but doesn't seem to have wide support on the phones yet.